# Реализовать права доступа для групп в Google таблице

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть потребность, но пока не знаю как реализовать.
Допустим есть таблица к которой имеют доступ ряд пользователей, которые могут добавляться. Они объеденены в несколько групп у которых есть доступ на редактирование разных частей таблицы. У кого есть идеи при помощи какого инструмента можно реализовать быстрое расшаривание этого доступа, добавлять в ручную это долго и чревато ошибками. 
Вот код который хочу взять за основу, но в ручную в скрипте прописывать пользователей и диапазоны это слишком ёмко, может есть более простое решение.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var protection = spreadsheet.getRange('NY1').protect();
protection.setDescription('Диапазон')
.removeEditors(['email']);
```

Спасибо за помощь

Comment: "на редактирование разных частей таблицы" далее можно не читать. Это фанатизм всех новичков. Так Таблицы не работают в принципе. Вопрос не по теме ruSO

Comment: @oshliaer Позволю себе не согласиться с вами. поясню, сейчас у меня реализован доступ, а точнее защита различных диапазонов от редактирования для разных пользователей, я хочу написать скрипт который будет расшаривать доступ, точнее ставить защиту диапазона примерный код допишу в вопросе. Если его писать так топорно как есть у меня идея он будет очень большим и не гибки, поэтому может кто более опытный может предложить более изящное решение.

Comment: Делайте как считаете нужным. Но вы решили придти на форум и просить помощи. Так вот самая лучшая помощь в данном вопросе - отговорить пытаться это сделать. Я как-то реализовал несколько задач, которые в режиме реального времени блокировали за пользователем диапазоны в зависимости от порядка ввода информации. Это не просто групповушка. Это работает только в фантазиях и на бумаге. В реальности появляются бесчисленные ... А в прочем, попробуйте. И да, сообщение все равно не по теме сообщества.